# Ember.js with Websockets / socket.io. Ember API Calls / Recommended Structure for Loading Real Time Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, websocket, socket.io, ember-data

I'm trying to integrate real-time data updates from the server in Ember.js, using socket.io. I've found https://gist.github.com/brentjanderson/4360857 which is an (incomplete, as far as I can tell) adapter to handle updates to the server initiated by the client using socket.io. After playing with it for a bit, I've managed to get a few operations to work.

So, Ember.js seems to have the swappable "adapter" layer to abstract updates from the browser and persist them to the server, in whatever format the developer needs. Does Ember.js have any sort of layer to handle updates the other way around, to hook into? What would need to be done to, "properly" handle real-time updates from the server?

[By the way, I'm considering Ember.js vs Meteor for an upcoming project, and only know a little bit about both]

Answer (score 1):

> Does Ember.js have any sort of layer to handle updates the other way around, to hook into?

No, there is not a separate layer for this.

> What would need to be done to, "properly" handle real-time updates from the server?

There does not seem to be an 'official' way to do this yet. There are a few good blog posts that show how to integrate with pusher. Should be pretty much the same pattern with socket.io

http://www.kaspertidemann.com/integrating-pusher-with-ember-js/
http://livsey.org/blog/2013/02/10/integrating-pusher-with-ember/

Also checkout this github project for a working example: https://github.com/devmynd/dashboard/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/lib/pusher.js